# Identifying orbital given electron probability density plot

Tags: physical-chemistry, orbitals, atoms, atomic-structure

[image: A probability density plot]

Being a high-school student, I only have a qualitative understanding of the wave mechanical model of atom.

Below are my inferences regarding the plot shown in the above picture:

The concerned orbital has $3$ radial nodes (I'm counting the places where the value of the y-coordinate is zero excluding the ones at the extreme left and right).

Hence, the orbital should satisfy $n-l-1=3$. The orbitals satisfying the condition are $4s, 5p, 6d, 7f,\ldots$.

Are my inferences correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your inference is correct, though the plot looks very awkward. There should be an exponential decay at large values of $r$, but in the plot the curve plunges sharply onto the $x$-axis. Also the shapes of each peak should not be so symmetric, but instead skewed towards the left.

Comment: Exactly... Which probably means that the right end is also a node, and the plot is not complete, or it's plotted incorrectly